# How to fill an NPArray with another array starting at a key in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, logistic-regression

I have a dataframe, called `x`. This consists of 2 columns which looks like this (712, 2):

```
     SibSp  Parch
731      0      0
230      1      0
627      0      0
831      1      1
391      0      0
.................
```

Due to logistic regression needing a 'free weight', I build a `newX` variable with the shape of my `x` data frame but blank values.

```
newX = np.zeros(shape=(x.shape[0], x.shape[1] + 1))
```

This generates a (712, 3) np array:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Since the first index (0) is a free weight, I want to now assign my x values to index 1 and 2.

```
newX[:, 1:] = x
```

However, it gives me this error:

> Exception: Dot product shape mismatch, (712,) vs (3, 712)

How can I fill my `newX` NPArray with my `x` array from keys 1-2 but keep all keys at 0 the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need adding `values` after the dataframe

```
newX[:, 1:] = x.values
newX
Out[171]: 
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! I knew there was something funky I was missing! Thanks so much for this answer - will mark when I can!

Comment: @Danny_P no worry , happy coding